# Angular SharedModule declarations not work

Tags: html, angular

I use EditableComponent from [EditableComponent Link](https://ng-run.com/edit/ITAGsPJhd87XeQwuhaAY?open=app%2Fapp.module.ts&layout=1)

declarations [EditableComponent,ViewModeDirective,EditModeDirective,EditableOnEnterDirective]
in appModule have work

but

declarations [EditableComponent,ViewModeDirective,EditModeDirective,EditableOnEnterDirective]
in SharedModule

imports[SharedModule] in appModule not work

module
SharedModule

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { EditableComponent } from './table-edittable/editable.component';
import { ViewModeDirective } from './table-edittable/view-mode.directive';
import { EditModeDirective } from './table-edittable/edit-mode.directive';
import { EditableOnEnterDirective } from './table-edittable/editable-on-enter.directive';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [EditableComponent,ViewModeDirective,EditModeDirective,EditableOnEnterDirective],
  exports: [EditableComponent,ViewModeDirective,EditModeDirective,EditableOnEnterDirective]
})
export class SharedDeclarationsModule {
}
```

module
appModule

```
import {SharedDeclarationsModule}from '../../layout-module/shared.declarstions.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [UserComponent,LeftsideComponent,DetailComponent,
    FocusableDirective,
  ],
  imports: [BrowserModule,HttpClientModule,CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    SharedDeclarationsModule
  ],
  exports:[UserComponent,LeftsideComponent,DetailComponent,SharedDeclarationsModule]
})
export class UserModule { }
```

Which part is wrong?

Sorry for not describing 'not work'
I represent with pictures:

not work img:

[image]

have work img:

[image]

Comment: Please be more specific. What does it mean "it doesn't work"?. Could you share the output from your `ng build` command so we can help you troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import CommonModule and export it. You can follow the documentation for creating a shared module. https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules

```
imports:      [ CommonModule ],
```

Comment: It succeeded! I tried for a long time. It turned out that the problem was just this..
Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear that. Check this answer so others can know that this is the correct one and worked for you.